# How to open a site when user click No on Uninstall Msgbox?

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Click on 'No' button and a site will open with default browser?

Thank you!

Comment: Pls make an example of a site

Comment: Why are you wanting to launch a web site when the user decides NOT to uninstall?  While I can understand (but am not a fan) of launching a web site when uninstalling, I've never seen a program launch a web site when I choose not to uninstall.

Comment: No, you've seen a program launch a website when you choose not to uninstall, on the screenshot picture I inserted in this post. Above.

Comment: No.  I've never seen a program launch a website when I chose "No." You've posted a picture of a dialog box not of a program that does it.  I've given an answer.  You might not like answer but InnoSetup cannot do anything when the "No" is selected.  The uninstall program ends.

Comment: Program in that screenshot picture can does it, if you need I can give you that installer. I did not lie to you.

Comment: That installer here: https://www.robot-soft.com/AutoMouseKey.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct API to detect that the user clicked *"No"*.

But knowing that the uninstaller:

- calls [`InitializeUninstall`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstall);
- displays the prompt;
- if user clicked "No", uninstallation is aborted and [`DeinitializeUninstall`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=DeinitializeUninstall) is called;
- if user clicked "Yes", uninstallation is started and as the very first thing, [`CurUninstallStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged) is called for the first time (with `usAppMutexCheck`).

So if `DeinitializeUninstall` is called without `CurUninstallStepChanged` ever being called, you know that the user clicked *"No"*.

```pascal
[Code]

var
  UninstallationStarted: Boolean;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  UninstallationStarted := True;
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if not UninstallationStarted then
  begin
    Log('User clicked No');
    ShellExec('open', 'https://www.example.com/uninstallationaborted', '', '',
              SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It work perfectly, thank you so much. Martin Prikryl. You're a Pro.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of limiting the launching of the website to just the "No" button.  You can use the `DeinitializeUninstall` procedure to perform actions when the uninstall is shutting down (which happens in both "Yes" and "No" clicks).

Here's an example of launching a website in a couple of different places:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{15B3741D-9217-4F84-971A-9F5DD837B50B}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[code]
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
var
 ErrCode : integer;
begin
   //This will launch the website before the "Do you want to remove..." dialog 
   ShellExec('open', 'http://google.com/', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrCode);
   result := true;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
 ErrCode : integer;
begin
  //This will launch the website after "yes" is clicked in the "Do you want to remove..." dialog.
  ShellExec('open', 'http://google.com/', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrCode);
end;
```

Comment: If you know the way please tell me know.

Comment: I've given you an answer.  There does not seem to be a way to perform an action when the "No" is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time edit your answer to give me a good hint. I already know what to do with my installer. Thank you.